# How can I force Yahoo to recrawl a site

Tags: search-engines, yahoo

I have a site that was hacked (someone hid a bunch of Viagra links and text on my pages).  I cleaned it up a few weeks ago, but the Yahoo results are still displaying the Viagra text in their descriptions, which is obviously bad for my sites reputation / etc...

I've dealt with Google already through their tool in webmaster tools, but cannot find a similar feature in Yahoo to make it re-index the site.

How can I tell Yahoo that the sites been updated?

Answer (score 3):

In the past, you could use the Yahoo! Site Explorer to manage your sitemaps with Yahoo!.

Since they now use Bing to power their searches, they [recommend you use the Bing webmaster Tools](http://l.yimg.com/pv/static/misc/index.html) instead.